# Position Absolute with Boundaries?

Tags: css, scroll, position, containers, center

I've provided a link below to an example illustrating perfectly what I'm asking.

I would like to know where to begin with something like this. I want to position an element to be centered while scrolling but somehow respect boundaries of some sort. Like this example (The It's a Big World finding your way textbox): https://ueno.co/work/lonely-planet

I do know about `position:absolute`, `float:left` and horizontally centering it. But I don't know how he got this box to only scroll a limited amount.

All I really need is a place to start, are there any tutorials? Tips? Places to start? I've used the identifier but I'm just lost on this. This would look wonderful on the website I'm building.

Any responses would be so helpful! I can provide a link to the website I'm working on in squarespace if it's needed, for now I just need a direction.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAlzB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, what you want is not possible using pure CSS. The example you show uses the React framework: https://facebook.github.io/react/

If you've got the time, and you want to do it the same way, you could follow the tutorial on that site.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tutorial, I'll give it a shot. I'm working with squarespace (using custom code is something I'm used to) I was wondering if you had any idea if something like this would work with Squarespace?